# IBM Bluemix cf python - can I specify pip version?

Tags: python, pip, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

When I deploy a python app using Cloud Foundry,
I can't find the way to specify the pip version when building the env.

Is there any way to change the pip version in the manifest.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python buildpack doesn't allow for a user-specified pip version. However, the pip version changes over time, so you could potentially just use a different version of the buildpack than what's installed in Bluemix.

See https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/releases for the pip version changes.

Then push your app using the `-b` option to specify the different buildpack. Say I wanted to use version v1.3.4, I would do:

```
cf push myapp -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack.git#v1.3.4
```